# How To Handle On Long Press Event For Entire Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, event-listener

I have a layout in my activity with some UI elements in it. I want to handle long press for the whole activity.Also I need to handle click events for all the UI events seperately. How can I do it? Pls help.

Comment: Do you want to handle long key press event for some specific keys or for all the keys?

Comment: for all keys. @Zohra Khan

Answer (score 2):

your class can use the interface `onLongClickListener`

like `yourclass extends Activity implements View.OnLongClickListener` which has the method that get notified on long press.

**Note:** Don't forget to set `yourView.setOnLongClickListener(this);` for all the views you need

Answer (score 1):

Rename your layout just the biggest of(linear layout, relative layout or...) in xml file and use this coDe

```
    Layout ly=(Layout) findVewById(R.id.yourlayout);
    ly.setOnLongClickListener (new.         Onlongclicklistener(){
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)   {
   //do something 
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of code an Activity subclass can use to implement special actions for a long press
CALL key:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL) {
        // a long press of the call key.
        // do our work, returning true to consume it.  by
        // returning true, the framework knows an action has
        // been performed on the long press, so will set the
        // canceled flag for the following up event.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Check http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009_12_01_archive.html

Comment: Key press is for harware buttons or soft keyboard, not for views